# Как в си без блокировки читать с потока ввода?

Tags: c

Я хочу посимвольно прочитать поток ввода. Я хочу сделать это с помощью getc, но проблема в том, что по достижению последнего символа getc просто блокирует поток выполнения, а не возвращает EOF, как в случае с файлом. Как сделать так, что при отсутствии данных в потоке getc или getchar не блокировали поток. Программа должна запускатсья как на виндовс, так и на линукс, по этому дескрипторы unix, который можно сделать неблокирущими и функция read не подходят.

Comment: переносимо — ни как... придётся писать под каждую платформу или пользоваться сторонней библиотекой...

Comment: Чтение файлов тоже является блокирующим и тоже может зависнуть, если устройство, с которого читается файл, начнёт тупить. Так что между файлом и потоком ввода на самом деле никаких значимых отличий нет

Comment: Если проблема только в EOF - ну, надо просто закрыть поток ввода :) - Ctrl-Z в Windows, в Linux, если не ошибаюсь, Ctrl-D...

Comment: Есть вариант с дополнительным независимым потоком. Ему даёте задачу, он блокирует мютекс и читает с потока данные. После того, как считал, разблокирет мютекс. Главная программа должна пытаться разблокировать мютекс с лимитом по времени. Если лимит исчерпан, то главная прога сама решает, что делать дальше. Можно всё написать, было-бы желание.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вы кое-что забыли, в си нет мютексов, а их поддержка в с11 и выше, не является обязательной.

Answer (score 0):

> по достижению последнего символа getc просто блокирует поток
> выполнения, а не возвращает EOF

Вы уверены? А вот если выполнить *man 3 getc* то мы увидим нечто прямо противоположное:

```
ОПИСАНИЕ
       Функция  fgetc()  считывает  очередной  символ  из  потока  stream  и возвращает unsigned char
       преобразованный в int, или EOF при достижении конца файла или при возникновении ошибки.
```